# Ошибка при вызове SetPriorityClass

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться, функции `Get/SetPriorityClass` возвращают 0(ошибка). Что я делаю не так?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    bool test;
    HANDLE disc = GetCurrentThread();

    test= SetPriorityClass(disc,REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
    cout<<test;
    cout<<GetPriorityClass(disc);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: посмотрите что возвращают GetLastError

Comment: GetLastError возвращает "6";

Comment: т.е. они говорят что хэндл неправильный

Comment: Может это из - за того что disc - псевдодискриптор?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SetPriorityClass/GetPriorityClass принимают первым параметром хэндл процесса, а у Вас дается хэндл потока

```
test = SetPriorityClass(GetCurrentProcess(),REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS);
```

Comment: Спасибо, все работает, еще вопрос по теме.Не может возникнуть проблем изменения класса на REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS?Планирую использовать классы приоритетов и приоритеты на олимпиадах по программированию.

Comment: проблемы, согласно законам Мерфи, возникают обязательно и в самое неподходящее время